# Too big GET/POST 503 error

Tags: php, http, get, http-status-code-503

**The problem was solved without changing anything, I think the host was f*cking some things up**

Im building a website with a few background requests, which use GET and POST statements, but that doesn't matter(for testing it I use GET).
When I request the page http://beta.svshizzle.com/check.php?email=a@b.c&ww=1423304826, it only shows me a 503 error page, which is not in my .htmlentities, so the standard one. If I request the same page without any GET values I get a normal response and also with ?email=A@B&.... I get a normal response, so I think that the problem is in the @ and the .(dot/period).

My php code(simplified):

```
<?php
echo "no error";
?>
```

Does anyone know the cause of this?

PS: Normal pages without GET values with an @ and a . do work as supposed, so I think it is not the server that is unavailable.

**Update**

LOG(Apache I thinks, not the php one):

```
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-92-186.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:13:58 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-93-123.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:14:31 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-92-51.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:14:59 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-92-193.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:15:31 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-92-151.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:15:59 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-66-249-93-0.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:16:33 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mediapartners-Google"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-82-170-27-149.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:16:43 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-82-170-27-149.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:16:48 +0100] "GET /signup/wwforgot.php?x=arendsurvey@gmail.com&h=868 HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
beta.svshizzle.com anon-82-170-27-149.ip.invalid - - [27/Jan/2016:17:19:04 +0100] "POST /check.php HTTP/1.1" 503 323 "http://beta.svshizzle.com/signin.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
```

This was the exact code I was using for debugging this problem, with only that piece of code it crashed, I don't know if it happens with no code.

I think urlencode doesn't work, because the php script doesn't even get started.

Comment: Check the webserver's error log.

Comment: Check apache and php error logs.

Comment: most likely you have a bug in the code which processes the emails, if you pass invalid email it works fine. Please update the question with exact php code you're using

Comment: Use urlencode(url) and let me knw if works

Comment: @MahmoudTantawy There were no PHP errors(only of previous bug, but those were fixed before this happened)